# Is "East or west India is the best" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, articles

In India there is a popular slogan:

> East or west India is the best.

Is this slogan grammatically correct?
I know directions have *the* before them.

> The east or the west India is the best.

Is this how the slogan should read?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it just needs a comma, or a dash.

> East or West, India is the best.

Otherwise, it sounds like you are saying "East India or West India is the best." Also, "the" is understood in this phrase and is not needed.

Comment: Yup, this is right. This slogan/chant is commonly used at cricket matches. The comma corrects the grammar